# Decomposing a set of complex matrices into orbits of the operation of conjugation

Tags: abstract-algebra, symmetry, jordan-normal-form, proof-explanation

I need some assistance with the proof for part (b) of the following problem statement:

> **Problem Statement:** Decompose the set $\mathbb{C}^{2\times2}$ of $2\times2$ complex matrices into orbits for the following operations of $GL_{2}(\mathbb{C})$:
>
> (a) left multiplication
>
> **(b) conjugation**

So, I was able to decompose $\mathbb{C}^{2\times2}$ into four orbits for part (a) *fairly* simply, but I am a little unsure how to go about part (b).

So I know that in the general case, the orbit of $A\in\mathbb{C}^{2\times2}$ is defined as: $$O_{A}=\left\{B\in\mathbb{C}^{2\times2} \mid B=P^{-1}AP \text{   for   } P\in GL_{2}(\mathbb{C})\right\}$$

I was thinking using the fact that for any $A\in\mathbb{C}^{2\times2}$ there is some $P\in GL_{2}(\mathbb{C})$ such that $B=P^{-1}AP$ has Jordan block form, being either a diagonal or triangular matrix? But this would not necessarily be true $\forall A\in\mathbb{C}^{2\times2}, P\in GL_{2}(\mathbb{C})$? Because any $A\in\mathbb{C}^{2\times2}$ would have a distinct $P\in GL_{2}(\mathbb{C})$ such that conjugation by $P$ results in the Jordan form of $A$?

Would the use of an equivalence relation defined as $A\sim B$ iff $B=P^{-1}AP$ for some $P\in GL_{2}(\mathbb{C})$ be helpful?

Comment: Jordan normal form is more or less the answer to this question; you just need to figure out when two Jordan normal forms are conjugate which is not so bad.

Comment: So should I consider cases of $A$ having two distinct eigenvalues, one distinct eigenvalue of multiplicity 2, and no eigenvalues?

Comment: There's no such thing as "no eigenvalues" over $\mathbb{C}$. We only have the first two cases.

Comment: Oh yes that's right. So for any matrix $A$ if it has two-distinct eigenvalues, it's Jordan form is a diagonal. If it has one-distinct eigenval, it is either diagonal or triangular (depending on the dimension of the eigenspace). But since we must consider conjugation by all invertible matrices, doesn't that mean that there will be some matrices $P^{-1}AP$ that are not Jordan form?

Comment: I mean, that's true, but every conjugacy class contains a matrix in Jordan normal form (this is sort of the point of Jordan normal form).

Comment: I am still a little confused. So would the decomposition of the set be $GL_2(\mathbb{C}) \begin{bmatrix}
    \lambda       & 0 \\
    0      & \lambda
\end{bmatrix} GL_2(\mathbb{C})$ or $GL_2(\mathbb{C}) \begin{bmatrix}
    \lambda_{1}       & 0 \\
    1      & \lambda_{2}
\end{bmatrix} GL_2(\mathbb{C})$

Comment: Those are two different collections of orbits, yes (although the notation you're using is not great because it looks like you're talking about double cosets, which you aren't).

Comment: so it would basically be a left coset? also should I have one coset for two distinct eigenvalues with a diagonal Jordan form?

Comment: It's not a coset at all. We're talking about conjugacy classes here.

Comment: Okay, so I am confused what notation I would use for a conjugate class. would it just be the sets of Jordan form matrices?

Comment: More or less, but again, there's a small detail here in that you need to check when two Jordan normal forms are conjugate.

Comment: Are you saying if a Jordan form is similar to another Jordan form? What would cause this, when a matrix is already in Jordan form and you conjugate it?